# Dynamic sql query with top count sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql

**My Requirement**

I need to set\get a variable's value using the dynamic query

I need to write a dynamic sql query to select top (@topCount)
The @topCount will need to be a calculated value using the dynamic sql query.

say eg

```
select @topCount = count(*) from dynamicTable where <<condition>>
```

then use this @topCount as  top (@topCount) in a dynamic query like

```
select top(@topCount) * from dynamicTable where <<condition>>
```

**What I have tried**

I have tried the below query to get the value of @topCount but it throws error.

```
set @sql = 'select ' + cast(@topCount as nvarchar(10)) +'= count(*) from parameterData where parameterID=2036';


--print @sql; 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Finally use the calculated totalCount from a dynamic Query to frame below query

```
set @sql = 'select top(' + cast(@topCount as nvarchar(10)) +' )  * FROM   '+ @table +' p  
    where 
parameterID= ' + cast(@parameterID as varchar(10)) '
```

**EDIT**

I have also tried this.

```
declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
declare @count3 int;
set @sql ='select @count3 = count(*) from parameterData where parameterID=1'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql,N'@count3 int',@count3;
print @count3;
```

tried casting too as below. BUt nothings get me the count of the records from the dynamic query. Any help please?

```
set @sql ='select '+cast(@count3 as nvarchar(10)) +'= count(*) from parameterData where parameterID=1'
```

Comment: your problem is that you have forgotten to select any columns

Comment: I have updated query to include *

Answer (score 2):

Use this format:

`select top N * from table;`

Note the asterisk - selecting all columns - or select specific columns.

I'm sure you can build that syntax into your string dynamically.

(Edited - initially I said the parentheses were not required, but thanks Martin - corrected on that, the parentheses are fine).

Comment: Thanks lot @youcantryreachingme  I am able to get the top records
Also help me get the count of rows into a variable say @count2 from the dynamic query to get the topCount

`--set @sql2 = 'select ' + cast(@count2 as nvarchar(10)) +'= count(*) from parameterData where parameterID=2036';
set @sql2 = 'select @count2 = count(*) from parameterData where parameterID=2036';
--print @sql2;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql2;
print @count2; `


This throws error -- Must declare the scalar variable "@count2"

Comment: The solution is literally the error message: "Must declare the scalar variable "@count2"". See in your question, you have `declare @count int;`? Now re-read the error: "must declare ... @count2".

Comment: You have the syntax on sp_executesql wrong, you need to add extra parameters, check the documentation or see this previous answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481189/exec-sp-executesql-with-multiple-parameters

Comment: @MArtin Yes with or without paranthesis it works, actually i had missed the * in that earlier.. @Mo64 For this query I have declared @count2 ==================>   `--set @sql2 = 'select ' + cast(@count2 as nvarchar(10)) +'= count(*) from parameterData where parameterID=2036'; set @sql2 = 'select @count2 = count(*) from parameterData where parameterID=2036'; --print @sql2; EXEC sp_executesql @sql2; print @count2`

Comment: @jAntoni - it's difficult to read your additional SQL in comments - the code does not wrap. Your last SQL starts with a comment (`--`) and the question is not clear. Consider updating your original question with all your questions laid out and easy to follow, or a new question. I am not even sure if your last comment is a question. You say you have declared @count2 - I cannot see the keyword `declare` anywhere in the SQL in your comment. In your original question you have `declare @count` but you do not have `declare @count2`.

Comment: The statement I have included while exceuting. But I have resolved it this way.

`declare @totalCount int;
set @sql = 'select @count = count(*)  FROM   '+ @table +' p  
 where 

 dateReceived >=  ''' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@FROMDATE, 101) + ''' 
 
 
 +''' and isActive=1';
 EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@count int out', @totalCount out;
 print @totalCount;`